# php shell_exec() change user or navigate to user folder

Tags: php, shell-exec

I would like to know if it was possible to use shell_exec as an other user.
The point is to access directly to the user folder (in home/user/)

Or, is it possible to navigate from var/www/ to home/user/ folder using shell_exec?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why not add apache\php as a member of a group with access to users folders

Comment: Ah I didn't know it was possible.

Comment: its a better idea than the hack approaches suggested by others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. You can change directory with `cd` command inside `shell_exec()`. But make sure you write subsequent commands in the same line after putting `;`

Like this,

```
shell_exec("cd .. ; pwd");
```

Above function will move directory to current's parent directory and display present working directory.

Answer (score 1):

just like the shell command.

```
`cd /home/user && you command`
```

``` '``' ```is similar to `shell_exec` in php